# How to save list of objects in django models?

Tags: python, django

I have a list of objects generated after some function, i want it to be saved in django model
i tried query set operation

```
mylist = [(u'england', u'1', u'cde', u'IMG1', u'CP1'), (u'england', u'1', u'cde', u'IMG2', u'CP1'), (u'england', u'2', u'abc', u'IMG1', u'CP1')] 

class Mymodel(models.Model):
   batch_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   batch_cola = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   batch_colb = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   batch_colc = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   batch_cold = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   batch_cole = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: what are you trying to do.please read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/#playing-with-the-api

Comment: are you trying to loop through the list and create three Mymodel instances using the values inside each tuple?

Comment: @dannymilsom yes exactly

Comment: @shashisp thought so - hopefully my answer helps you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) method - something like:

```
Mymodel.objects.bulk_create([Mymodel(**{'batch_cola' : m[0],
                                        'batch_colb' : m[1],
                                        'batch_colc' : m[2],
                                        'batch_cold' : m[3],
                                        'batch_cole' : m[4]})
                            for m in mylist])
```

Instead of iterating over the objects and calling `save()` on every single one of them, this method results in a single database hit for all the objects, as opposed to one hit for each object.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - you create all items in a single query instead of making repeated trips to the database.

Comment: I think there's a missing ")" after the "}"

Answer (score 2):

Creating new instances of a model are well documented - see [creating objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects)

But to explicitly anwser your question - one solution is to loop over the list of tuples, pass the appropriate keyword arguments to the model class and then call [save()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save). The last bit is important, otherwise there will be no database level transaction.

```
for t in mylist:
    Mymodel(batch_cola=t[0], batch_colb=t[1],
           batch_colc=t[2], batch_cold=t[3],
           batch_cole=t[4]).save()
```

You can also use the convenience [create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#create) function from the models manager - you don't need to call [`.save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) then.

```
for t in mylist:
    Mymodel.object.create(batch_cola=t[0], batch_colb=t[1],
           batch_colc=t[2], batch_cold=t[3], batch_cole=t[4])
```

The docs say that the two are [equivalent](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#create) - so its somewhat a matter of preference.

On a side note, there is a naming convention in Python you should follow when creating Classes - *"Class names should normally use the CapWords convention."* - [see PEP-8 guidelines](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i used Mymodel.objects.create() it works great!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ForeignKey` relationship to have a list of objects "contained" by parent object.

Example:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
```

Then:

```
p = Parent.objects.create(name="p")
c = p.child_set.create(name="c")
c2 = p.child_set.create(name="c2")

p.child_set.count()  # Should be 2
```

For further information refer to ForeignKey documentation in Django.